# Retrieve Structured Table from Old Version Excel in SharePoint Using Power Automate

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a Macro-enabled Excel file stored in SharePoint Document Library, the Excel file consists of structured table. When I use "List Rows Present in a Table" I managed to retrieve the table columns I need from latest version Excel file in SharePoint.

But, if I try to retrieve the version 20 days earlier, it is either not able to find the Table (using List Rows Present in a Table approach) or not able to Parse binary data (using Get file content or Get file content using path approach). I am looking for solution to retrieve the structured table in the old Excel file.

I am still new to Power Automate, is there a way for me to retrieve the Table from 20 days earlier version history Excel file?

Comment: Not via PowerAutomate, no.